# Disable all transitions in VuetifyJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, transition, vuetify.js

How to disable all **transitions** like `slide-x-transition` or the [dialog modal scale transition](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs#example-modal) in VuetifyJS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just playing with the examples on CodePen and I believe you can disable the transition by simply using a value which does not exist in the framework eg. `transition="none"`.

If you remove the `transition` property then it will default to the fade transition.

Comment: Do you have an idea on how to disable the transition for the [bottom sheet](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/bottom-sheets#introduction) as well? `transition="none"` doesn't work for me. Here is a CodePen: [https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JaRezy](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JaRezy)

Comment: That is a tricky one. Are you able to add custom CSS? If you could add a custom global CSS file in your application then you could disable the transitions using CSS like this `.v-bottom-sheet.v-dialog { transition: none }`

Comment: I am stuck at the same place. Has anyone figured this out. I want to disable the transition on the v-select menu